# Using STM32F103C6 SPI just for reading an EEPROM 25AA010A data

Tags: proteus, eeprom, keil, stm32f103

No matter what is written before, is that possible?
Without knowing what data is written inside of an EEPROM 25AA010A, I want to read it using STM32F103C6 SPI. I write and read before on it, but now I need to just read

[image]

Comment: it would be enough if I could see the read data on the virtual terminal in proteus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to always read that memory chip.

With that or any other MCU.

With MCU SPI or without MCU SPI.